# Excel function to insert few letters into every blank cell in entire column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've been trying to understand how to make a function like that but couldn't figure it out. I have a column (`I2:I48`) with some values but also `empty cells` and I want to put let's say `"123"` in every empty cell and do nothing if cell has values already.

```
=IF(I2:II48 = "","123","")
```

This one isn't working for me. Thanks everybody for future help.

Comment: in witch cell do you try to do that? You can not recursive call cells (normally).

Comment: http://www.contextures.com/xlDataEntry02.html

Answer (score 1):

As the way you want to do, someone corrects me if I'm wrong, you can't. You would need to do it in a different column or with VBA. In your case, you would need the column J and put the function you've created:

Column I, you keep the values.
Column J, you check each row `=if(I1="",123,I1)`, then `=if(I2="",123,I2)` and so on...